# xcode beta 3 Cocoapods all-product-headers.yaml error

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode6

Having an error building my swift application using AFNetworking via CocoaPods. In beta 2 it works fine, but in beta 3, I get:

"/Users/leifashley/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/all-product-headers.yaml:4:13: error: Could not find closing ]!
  'roots': ["

When I look at the YAML, it is indeed unfinished. So my questions:
1. Is there a way to fix this, even temporarily?
2. Is there a way to turn off POD support in the workspace/projects until this is ironed out in a future Xcode release?

I'll post updates if I find a solution.

Comment: See the above-linked question. It's a known bug, with a workaround described there.